# gitlab sefl-managed troubleshooting email

Tags: git, gitlab, exchange-server

we have a self-managed free version of Gitlab (GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.7.5-ee) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in ourdomain.com private network, we followed installation guide available on Gitlab official website.

After installation completed, we started to configure email, note we have exchange relay server inside our private network domain with no authentication required and its using default port so it should be easy configuration we thought but we were wrong!, in below I will explain in details steps I've tried and i hope someone can tell me what i have missed or miss-configured:

1. take backup of gitlab.rb file
2. add below lines to gitlab.rb file.

```
# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "relay IP address"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
# gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "ourdomain.com"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = false
# gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
# git_data_dirs({ "default" => { "path" => " /media/ibrahim/# Data/gitlab/git-data" } })
```

3. sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure, and by the way last line in above code have changed the repository directory as i wanted successfully, but I'm not sure about email function:)
4. sudo gitlab-ralis console, and try to send email from console

```
Notify.test_email('me@ourdomain.com', 'subject testing', 'hi testing testing').deliver_now
```

Email failed and in response there was a small error message hint ***/usr/sbin/sendmail not found***

5. So after searching the internet i found couple of troubleshooting options as below:

   - check with Exchange relay server admin, and make sure my server was allowed/ added in allow list, ***Done***.
   - check with firewall admin, and make sure my server was not having any restriction to communicate with exchange relay, ***Done***.
   - check if exchange server and port allowed from your Gitlab server using telnet, and if allowed try sending a test email, which was all success and email received, ***Done***.

```
    telnet 10.100.24.1 25 (if successfully connection will open)
    helo (if successfully exchange will response with hello)
    MAIL FROM:gitlab@ourdomain.com (will setup From Email)
    RCPT to:me@ourdomain.com (will setup To email)
    DATA (will setup message content)
    Subject: Hellllo brother (email subject and must give free line before content)

    Dear Me :),  (message, and should end up with a free line then . to execute email sending)
    this is a testing email send to you from Gitlab server, please call me on mobile if your recieved it.

    .
```

- check if Gitlab server is having right Date and Time, ***Done***.
- in Gitlab site go to admin area--> monitoring--> background jobs and see if there is any pending or rescheduled jobs for emails but i found none. (if this is the problem then restarting sidekiq the background jobs manager or entire Gitlab application should fix the issue.) ***Done***.
- finally decided to go deeper and troubleshoot ***/usr/sbin/sendmail not found***

so i decided to follow 1 internet post and do following:

```
sudo apt install sendmail
sudo apt install mailutilis
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

then i went again and tried to send an email from (sudo gitlab-ralis console), which failed again but this time it toke almost 2 mins to respond, no error messages!! and the email was never received!!

so, after internet searching i found 1 interesting post and while executing the recommended pieces of code i go below results:

```
sudo gitlab-ralis console
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method
response was ---> sendmail (should it be smtp ??)
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings  
response was ---> {:address=>"localhost", :port=>25, 
domain=>"localhost.localdomain", :user_name=>nil, :password=>nil, 
authentication=>nil, :enable_starttls_auto=>true}
```

i have no idea what to do next ?? can someone advise?. thank you all.

Comment: You have a *lot* of typos. Please take the time to proofread

Comment: Aside from that, good job following instructions